# JSch with encrypted putty private (ppk) for authentation

Tags: java, encryption, ssh, key, sftp

I have been stuck for a while to get the SFTP auth through Java JSch.

The following code snippet works if the ppk is not encrypted:

```
    jsch.addIdentity(username, certificateBytes , null, null);
```

However, the ppk is encrypted. I tried to pass the password of the key to jsch as:

```
    jsch.addIdentity(username, certificateBytes , null, "password");
```

It doesn't work since jsch seems doesn't support to decrypt ppk. I am wondering how can I decrypt the encrypted ppk in Java?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

JSch supports encrypted .ppk key files.

But it supports only version 2 of the .ppk format. Maybe your encrypted .ppk file is in the new version 3, which is produced by PuTTYgen 0.75 and newer. Such keys start like this:

```
PuTTY-User-Key-File-3: ssh-rsa
Encryption: aes256-cbc
...
```

If that's the case, you will have to use PuTTYgen to convert the key to the version 2.